# Chatter emails not receiving- Hyperforce migration

Tags: email, hyperforce

Suddently our entire team stopped receiving Chatter emails post Hypeforce migration.
Our instance location is United States.

Can you please guide to enable the same again ?
I have already tried multiple domains/IP addresses but it's not working.

Please help.

Comment: You need to open a case with Salesforce.

Comment: Check https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385742&type=1